# Traffic simulator tool for Mariadb?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I made a MariaDB Tuning course, and it's very important to test the system with real traffic and real data, simulate a Production server basically.

The data is easy to replicate, just a dump, or even replication for have the database updated. But how do you test your traffic for make statistics? You can't replicate your users and their consumption of the server's resources, can you?

Do you know any tool that I could use for simulating this traffic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no 100% real workload replication tools for MySQL (at least 100% free)

All you could do is only simulate:

- using [HammerDB](http://hammerdb.com/)
- a very interesting tool from Percona, [Percona playback](https://github.com/Percona-Lab/query-playback) and [related article](https://www.percona.com/blog/2012/10/25/replaying-database-load-with-percona-playback/)
- you can also look for [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org)
- you can sometimes enable the general log on MySQL server, and use it to prepare tests with JMeter (after manual preparation)

With Playback - You can not replay collisions as it was on real server
With JMeter (and similar). You would need to define queries by yourself.

Depending from what you want to demonstrate it could be easy or hard to prepare a proper simulation.

Sometimes for proper problem simulation all you need is [mysqlslap](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqlslap.html). Run 3-4 instances with different queries and you can simulate locks, deadlocks etc.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL comes with a handy little diagnostic tool called **mysqlslap** that's been around since version 5.1.4. It's a benchmarking tool that can help DBAs and developers load test their database servers.

mysqlslap can emulate a large number of client connections hitting the database server at the same time. The load testing parameters are fully configurable an the results from different test runs can be used to fine-tune database design or hardware resources.

I would make a copy of the production database for testing and ensure if you are on a different server, that it has the same specifications as the production server.

Ensure that you are not running your test on the same production server.